# Дасьте чи дасте?

Tags: дієслова, дієвідмінювання

Набираючи повідомлення у Skype, помітив, що слово *дасьте* (майбутній час від *"давати"*) підкреслюється червоною лінією. Натомість, слово *дасте* не підкреслюється. Завжди думав, що правильно *"дасьте"*.

**Як правильно?**

Також буду вдячний за пояснення, чому саме так.

PS: у формі питання цього сайту слово *дасьте* також підкреслюється.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Дасте* — це [єдино](http://sum.in.ua/s/davaty) правильна форма.

Вживання *дасьте* особисто я ніколи не зустрічав. Google не знаходить жодного джерела, яке вказувало б, що можна писати таким чином, тож це помилка.

Comment: Ось тут знайшов вживання, яке більш-менш заслуговує уваги: https://uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0:%D0%A1%D1%8C%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE_%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%96_%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D1%83.pdf/181

Comment: Схоже, що це застаріла форма, до того ж у церковному письмі.

Comment: Вживань насправді [багато](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="дасьте") (і не лише у церковному письмі), але я думаю, Ви абсолютно праві, що це застаріла форма.

Answer (score 1):

У множині другої особи (те, що співвідноситься із займенником "ви") дієслова "дати", "їсти", "відповісти" [набувають форму](http://slovnyk.ua/?swrd=%C4%E0%F2%E8&x=0&y=0) на "-сте": ви їсте, ви дасте, ви відповісте. Це специфічні дієслова.

Comment: http://slovnyk.ua/?swrd=%C4%E0%F2%E8&x=0&y=0

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian.SE! Будь ласка, перевірте правила, які ви оголошуєте. Наприклад, *«їсте»* — це теперішній час, а *«дасте»* — майбутній.